# How to run multiple logins at a time with using for loop?

Tags: java, android, k-9mail

I'm working with k-9 mail. All the setup steps was done perfectly, But as per my requirement, I want multiple accounts open with multiple credentials present. I tried with `for` loop with different threads but its take last login only execution!

I tried with like this but it doesn't work.

Any one please give suggestions...

```
gmail_creds= Helpers.getArrayList(WelcomeMessage.this,"email_creds");
   for( int i=0;i<gmail_creds.size();i++){
final  int j=i;
                  //k

       new Thread(new Runnable() {

                public void run(){

                    Helpers.saveStringInSP(WelcomeMessage.this,"userEmail", gmail_creds.get(j).userEmail);
                    Helpers.saveStringInSP(WelcomeMessage.this,"userPassword",gmail_creds.get(j).userPassword);

                    AccountSetupBasics.actionNewAccount(WelcomeMessage.this);


                 }
            }).start();




        }
```

Comment: Do you have any code or its just a concept as of now?

Comment: @Rohit5k2 thanks for reply u can see above sample code snippet i tried....

Comment: Probably you are overwriting something.

Comment: yaa @Rohit5k2 checked many times..I think i did n't overwrite anything

Answer (score 1):

Try the following and let me know.

Note: I haven't fully test it.

```
gmail_creds= Helpers.getArrayList(WelcomeMessage.this,"email_creds");
List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<Thread>();
for( int i = 0; i < gmail_creds.size(); i++){
    final int j = i;
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run(){
            Helpers.saveStringInSP(WelcomeMessage.this,"userEmail", gmail_creds.get(j).userEmail);
            Helpers.saveStringInSP(WelcomeMessage.this,"userPassword",gmail_creds.get(j).userPassword);
            AccountSetupBasics.actionNewAccount(WelcomeMessage.this);
        }
    })
    t.start();
    threads.add(t);
}

// Let all threads to finish execution prior continuing main thread.
try {
    for(Threat t: threads){
        t.join();
    }
} catch(InterruptedException ie){
    ie.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Yaaa it's working perfectly acarlstein's ...thank you...you're save my day

Comment: @raviteja, I am glad to be of help :)

Comment: Hii acarlstein it's working nice but sometimes same account logged repeatedly(example i want login two accounts one after another sometimes its logged correctly but sometimes its logged same account  two times instead of second account...can you give any suggestions....

Comment: @raviteja it sounds to me that you may be having a racing condition. For example, it could be that gmail_creds is an ArrayList and those are not synchronized. You may have to synchronize the block that is doing the work, apply Collection.synchronizeLIst, or CopyOnWriteArrayList with those ArrayList.

Comment: gmail_synclist=new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
        gmail_synclist = Helpers.getArrayList(WelcomeMessage.this, "email_creds");
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    synchronized (gmail_sylist) {
                        Helpers.saveStringInSP(WelcomeMessage.this, "userEmail", gmail_synclist.get(j).userEmail);
                        Helpers.saveStringInSP(WelcomeMessage.this, "userPassword",gmail_synclist.get(j).userPassword);
                        AccountSetupBasics.actionNewAccount(WelcomeMessage.this);
                    }

Comment: I tried with above but it doesn't work could you please give code example

Comment: @raviteja  In the example you are providing, I see that you put all my suggestions together. I'm sorry. I can't give you an example because I can't replicate your code. I can only make assumptions based on what you provide and try to rule out things in hopes to help you. Perhaps, you need to try something else than Thread/Runnable. Here is my multithreading examples: https://github.com/acarlstein/java-core-course/tree/master/src/main/threading/multithreading, also take a look to the unit tests: https://github.com/acarlstein/java-core-course/tree/master/src/test/threading/multithreading

Comment: The links I provided you are other ways that you can do multi-threading, including the one you are putting in effect. Check the source and the unit tests and let me know if perhaps this inspire you to try a different approach to your problem.